# How to wrap an existing event driven library into NGRX?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

How do you wrap an existing JS library with NGRX. The library needs to be initialised before it periodically emits a variety of events. I've not been able to find an example of this kind of solution.

My guess is something like this: An @Effect listens for an INIT action and initialises the library, sets up listeners and dispatches actions when the listener emits events.

Edit: this seems to work:

```
@Effect()
Initialise$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType<ExampleActions.Initialise>(ExampleActions.INITIALISE)
    .withLatestFrom(this.store$)
    .switchMap(([action, storeState]) => {
        const dispatched$ = new Subject<Action>();

        // Instantiate library
        const library = new Library(storeState.libraryOptions);

        library.onEventA(event =>
            dispatched$.next(new ExampleActions.ThingAHappened(event.info))
        );

        library.onEventB(event =>
            dispatched$.next(new ExampleActions.ThingBHappened(event.info))
        );

        return dispatched$;
    });
```

But is there a better way and how would this be implemented?

Comment: It might help if you could give an example of how the "existing JS library" is used.

Comment: Thanks @bygrace. I'm seeking a sanity check now that the example seems to be working. Should this even be in an Effect?

Comment: Yeah, looks like it should work. As far as whether it belongs there, that is more of a mater of opinion. Where are you firing the `INITIALISE` event? You might consider using `APP_INITIALIZER` to map 3rd party events to action dispatches. If you keep it in an effect you might want to check out the `fromEventPattern` operator.